# Create list in one form, show list values in listbox at second form

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

[image]

Here is the image what i'm trying to create at the moment.

Basically i want to write down Name, Surname, Age and Add new student to list.
After that i want the student to show in listbox , but listbox is in another form.
My problem is that i can't get to listbox that is in another form. Do i have to create one more list in new form aswell?

My Code:
**Form1:**

```
 public class Students
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} \t\t {1} \t\t {2}", Name, Surname, Age);
        }
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Students> stud = new List<Students>();
        public Form1()
        {
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void addNewStudentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(stud);
            f2.MdiParent = this;
            f2.Show();
        }

        private void showAllStudentsInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3(stud);
            f3.MdiParent = this;
            f3.Show();
        }
    }
```

**Form2:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(List<Students> stud)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            studnew = stud;
        }
        List<Students> studnew;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Students student = new Students();
            student.Name = textBox1.Text;
            student.Surname = textBox2.Text;
            student.Age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            studnew.Add(student);
        }
    }
```

**Form3:**

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3(List<Students> stud)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        studnewf3 = stud;
    }
    List<Students> studnewf3;

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Name \t\t Surname \t\t Age");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(student); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Just store the passed list to the `Form3` constructor in a form field like you did in `Form2`

Comment: Take a look at `Application.Openforms`

Comment: Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: Practicing before exams. Not really homework.

Comment: Store it in a database, and then query the database to populate the other form.

Comment: @IvanStoev that's the sadest part, i don't understand how to get student in Form3 out of Form3. I have updated my question's Form3 abit. But don't know if it's any right.

Comment: But as I understand, you want just to show all the students from the list in `Form3`, right? In `Form3_Load`, add `foreach (var student in studnewf3) listBox1.Items.Add(student);`

Comment: @IvanStoev oops, that's it. Thank you.

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted to have both forms open at the same time and pass it over while they were open and have it display in Form3's immediately.  Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing around a List pass a BindingList. In this way you could leverage the automatic notification when a new element is added to the BindingList

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Students> stud = new List<Students>();
    BindingList<Students> bsStud;
    public Form1()
    {
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        InitializeComponent();
        bsStud = new BindingList<Students>(stud);
    }

    private void addNewStudentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(bsStud);
        f2.MdiParent = this;
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void showAllStudentsInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(bsStud);
        f3.MdiParent = this;
        f3.Show();
    }
```

In Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    BindingList<Students> bsStudnew;

    public Form2(BindingList<Students> bs)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bsStudnew = bs;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Students student = new Students();
        student.Name = textBox1.Text;
        student.Surname = textBox2.Text;
        student.Age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        bsStudnew.Add(student);
    }
}
```

In form3

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3(BindingList<Students> bsStud)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = bsStud;
    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare  form2 on form1 and get list of students.
 on Form1:

```
public Form2 f2;
private void     showAllStudentsInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object       sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(f2.ListOfStudent);
        f3.MdiParent = this;
        f3.Show();
    }
```

On the form2 make the list of students public.

```
Public List<Students> studnew;
```

OR you can create an event on form2 that occur when student added and on form1 response  to that event on Form2:

```
Public event EventHandler<Student> StudentAdded;
public void SayToForm1ThatStudentHasAdded (Student s)
{
EventHandler <Student> sa;
if (sa!=null)
{sa (this,s);}
}
```

And like  other event use this event :on Form1:

```
private void addNewStudentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(stud);
        f2.MdiParent = this;
        f2.StudentAdded+=ResponseToEvent;
        f2.Show();
    }

    void ResponseToEvent  (object sender,Student e)
 {
      List of Student. Add (  e);
}
```